# Angular2 - Release candidate router not routing to child routes

Tags: typescript, angular

I am trying to create a simple nested router. This sort of structure worked in the beta builds, but with the launch of the release candidate router I find myself stuck.

http://plnkr.co/edit/nn7KSJpqWuBpkxi1E6tJ

The plunkr above is a contrived version of my scenario. Despite having

```
@Routes([
  new Route({ path: '/applications/...', component: ApplicationRouter })
])
```

the router doesn't appear to be recognising the non-terminal route.

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Cannot match any routes. Current segment: 'applications'. Available routes: ['/applications/...'].
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the new router `/...` isn't necessary for routes that have child routes.

Comment: *sigh* yep got it in one again Gunter. The documentation says to still use `...` and I haven't seen it mentioned anywhere to remove that. Thanks!

Comment: I think I have seen that as well somewhere but when I tried, it only worked without.

Comment: I created a child route with cli: ng generate parent/child and cli created '...', which broke the route removing the '...' solved my problem. Thanks